# How can I access value of particular node

Tags: javascript

I have below function and I am getting values in row and I have printed values in console.log as per below.

```
this.lookup.select$.subscribe((row) => {
      console.log(row);
      this._lookupForm.patchValue({'selected': row});
    });
```

Please see attached screenshot for more details, I want to access particular value from this row data.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row is a javascript object. you can access the property's value simply this way :

row['complianceEpiryDate']